# xamarin - CustomAdapter with buttons in ListView

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I just made simple `CustomAdapter` for `ListView` with clickable button.

This is my adapter which on button click will `toast` an item position:

```
public class ViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public TextView txtName { get; set; }
        public TextView txtAge { get; set; }
        public TextView txtEmail { get; set; }
        public Button button1 { get; set; }
    }
    public class CustomAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {
        private Activity activity;
        private List<Person> persons;

        public CustomAdapter(Activity activity,List<Person> persons)
        {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.persons = persons;
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return persons.Count;
            }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return persons[position].Id;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var view = convertView;

            if (view == null)
            {
                view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_view_dataTemplate, parent, false);

                var txtName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
                var txtAge = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
                var txtEmail = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);
                var button1 = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);

                view.Tag = new ViewHolder() { txtName = txtName, txtAge = txtAge, txtEmail = txtEmail, button1 = button1 };
            }

            var holder = (ViewHolder)view.Tag;

            holder.txtName.Text = "name " + position;
            holder.txtAge.Text = "age " + position;
            holder.txtEmail.Text = "email " + position;
            holder.button1.Click += delegate
            {
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "pos: " + position.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            };

            return view;

        }
```

My problem is that, when I click on this button **once**, I Get few `Toasts` one by one. Like `"pos: 1" => "pos: 2" => "pos: 3" => "pos: 0"` For diffrent rows, the `Toast` messages pop in different way.

I am struggling with this problem couple of hours and I cant find a way to solve this problem.

I have made an Github [repo](https://github.com/gregg95/CustomAdapterWithButton) with whole "test project" so you can see exacly what I am talking about.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the view recyclation feature in Android.

You are checking if the `convertView` is not null, which is correct, but when it is not null, you are setting its properties including the `Click` event handler.

The problem is, that when you use `+=`, a **new event handler is added** to those already existing, so when the view is recycled several times, the button may have **several event handlers attached** and that causes several toast messages to appear.

To fix this, you should add the event handler within the initial `view` creation only:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
        var view = convertView;

        if (view == null)
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_view_dataTemplate, parent, false);

            var txtName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            var txtAge = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
            var txtEmail = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);
            var button1 = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);

            view.Tag = new ViewHolder() { txtName = txtName, txtAge = txtAge, txtEmail = txtEmail, button1 = button1 };
            button1.Tag = position;
            button1.Click += (sender, args) => {
               Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "pos: " + ((Button)sender).Tag.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            };
        }

        var holder = (ViewHolder)view.Tag;

        holder.txtName.Text = "name " + position;
        holder.txtAge.Text = "age " + position;
        holder.txtEmail.Text = "email " + position;
        holder.button1.Tag = position;
        return view;    
    }
```

Note that I am setting the `position` as the tag of the `button`. I originally used the `position` variable in the event handler directly, but unfortunately this doesn't work, as when the variable is used inside the handler, it is hoisted and it would always refer to the original `position` when the view was created. Using `sender`'s `Tag` you can always retrieve the current value as expected.

### Update

As a simplification as suggested by **@pskink**, you could add a `position` property and `ShowToast` method to your `ViewHolder`. Then you could use the `ViewHolder` directly in the `Click` handler and the code would be much simpler:

Updated `ViewHolder`:

```
public class ViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public TextView txtName { get; set; }
    public TextView txtAge { get; set; }
    public TextView txtEmail { get; set; }
    public Button button1 { get; set; }

    public int position { get; set; }

    public void ShowToast()
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "pos: " + position.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

And updated `GetView`:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    var view = convertView;

    if (view == null)
    {
        view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_view_dataTemplate, parent, false);

        var txtName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
        var txtAge = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
        var txtEmail = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);
        var button1 = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);

        var viewHolder = new ViewHolder() { txtName = txtName, txtAge = txtAge, txtEmail = txtEmail, button1 = button1 };
        view.Tag = viewHolder;

        button1.Click += (sender, args) => {
            viewHolder.ShowToast();
        };

    }

    var holder = (ViewHolder)view.Tag;

    holder.txtName.Text = "name " + position;
    holder.txtAge.Text = "age " + position;
    holder.txtEmail.Text = "email " + position;
    holder.position = position;

    return view;
}
```

Comment: i am not an expert in c# but how `position` is going to work in that code? imho you have to call `AdapterView#getPositionForView` somewhere...

Comment: I have updated the answer with explanation, originally there was a but in the code, but the current solution works as expected. `position` is passed in the `GetView` as parameter. I can reference it from an inline event handler, but that would cause the problem I described below the code, so the current solution is better.

Comment: isn't it better that `ViewHolder` implements `OnClickListener` and `ViewHolder` also keeps `int position`? those tags are a nightmare...

Comment: Nice idea! I have updated the answer with your suggestion :-)

Comment: nice, but it is not possible in c# to do `button1.Click += viewHolder` ? (assuming that `class ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener` - of course this is java pattern and i dont know if its possible in c#)

Comment: Unfortunately not, in C# the `Click` handler is just a simple method, not a class which implements a `Listener` type. Sometimes that makes things a bit more complex :-D .

Comment: Thank you so much guys, you saved lots of my time :)

Comment: Wish you happy coding, Grzegorz :-) !

Comment: @MartinZikmund last question: so you cannot also call in c#: `button1.setOnClickListener(viewHolder)` ? is that method somehow "hidden"?

Comment: No, in fact it is still there as an alternative (`SetOnClickListener`) and to use it, you have to create a `class` implementing `IOnClickListener`. Unfortunately as compared to Java, we cannot create the class "inline" which makes creating listeners this way less convenient than using the `Click` event handler, which can be attached inline :-) .